# How to uncheck all checkbox in treeview nodes?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

i am working on an application in asp.net.I have used a treeview to show Category.After storing the checked node value into database i want to uncheck all the treeview nodes. for this i have the following code:

```
foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
        {
            node.Checked=false;

        }
```

but it is showing error:
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

please help me.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**foreach** is **read only**  and you can't change collection into foreach.
you must use **for loop**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TreeView1.Nodes.Count; i++)
{
     TreeView1.Nodes[i].Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
for(int i=0; i<TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count; i++)
{
   TreeNode node = TreeView1.CheckedNodes[i];
   node.Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CheckedNodes.Count variable is re-evaluated on each pass.   So just keep clearing the check box at the 0 index.

```
int tvCT;
tvCT = TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count;
if (tvCT > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tvCT; i++)
    {
        TreeNode node = TreeView1.CheckedNodes[0];
        node.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
{
    TreeView1.CheckedNodes[0].Checked = false;
}
```

This is a pretty simple block that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes)
            {
                node.Checked = false;
                foreach (TreeNode item1 in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    item1.Checked = false;

                    foreach (TreeNode item2 in item1.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        item2.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Check it.....! it's work